# TransactionScope com múltiplas StoredProcedures

Tags: c#, .net, transações

Estou pensando em implementar `TransactionScope` no meu código, porém, todos os acessos a banco são realizados por `StoredProcedures`.

O `TransactionScope` consegue dar `rollback` em múltiplas ações realizadas em `StoredProcedures`?

```
using (var trans = new TransactionScope()) {
  try {
    this.Teste1Repository.Insert(); //  Chamada a primeira PROC
    this.Teste2Repository.Insert(); //  Chamada a segunda PROC

    trans.Complete();
  }
  catch {
  //  Trata erro
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a primeira StoredProcedure SP1 emitir um commit, as alterações que já tenham sido feitas serão permanentes. Nesse caso, se a SP2 falhar, as alterações feitas pela SP1 não serão revertidas.

Ou você controla as operações do seu sistema via Código, ou via Banco de dados.

Caso queira controlar os RollBacks via código, terá que reescrever toda a função da Procedure para C#.

**Fonte: Experiência própria.**

EDIT 1: Teste este conceito, utilizando *SQLCommand* do C#.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18718722/6579651

Comment: OBS.: Caso queira continuar utilizando as Procedures, terá de implementar o Rollback nela mesma. Segue um exemplo em SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13171451/6579651

Comment: No caso, as procs não possuem transactions. Portanto, o rollback do TransactionScope funcionaria, correto?

Comment: Não funcionaria, pois o que importa neste caso é o Commit, visto que a SP1 ja executou toda sua função, deu um commit, voltou para o C# e executou a SP2. Neste caso você teria que juntar as 2 Procedures em 1 só, e fazer o tratamento do Rollback dentro da mesma.

Comment: Mesmo sem ter o código iniciando uma transaction e realizando o commit? Pois as minhas procs não possuem transaction/commit/rollback.

Comment: @ClaudioNeto não estou entendendo qual a sua dificuldade. Respondi sua pergunta logo acima, o que está dando errado aí?